# Which is fastest? closest() vs manual traversing in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom

I have this code

```
<td>
  <div class='DivA'>
    <a href='#' class='LinkA'>Upload</a>
    <a href='#' class='LinkB'>Upload</a>
    <a href='#' class='LinkC'>Upload</a>
    <a href='#' class='LinkD'>Upload</a>
    <a href='#' class='LinkE'>Upload</a>
    <a href='#' class='LinkF'>Upload</a>
    <a href='#' class='LinkG'>Upload</a>
   </div>
   <div class='DivB'>Some Stuff</div>
    </td>
```

What is the most efficient way of accessing LinkG on click of LinkB. I have come up with these best solutions (in my opinion) but having hard time which is the quickest one.

```
$('.LinkB').closest(".LinkG");
```

or

```
$('.LinkB').parent().find('.LinkG');
```

Comment: First one is fastest, because the second one will never find what you need.

Comment: http://www.jsperf.com - For all your "which is fastest" js needs.

Comment: `.closest` doesn't *literally* mean "closest".  It means "the first parent to match".

Comment: closest in general is pretty slow...

Comment: You probably want `.siblings()`.  `$('.LinkB').siblings(".LinkG");`

Comment: Your update made the answers invalid.

Comment: First time I've given a question a `-1`, but it's because your question's options are fundamentally wrong and you made a major edit instead of closing and asking a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These do different things.

`.closest('.DivB')` will traverse the DOM tree up until it finds an element that matches the selector (probably none).

`.parent().next()` will do what it looks like it will do, find the parent then its next sibling.

What you want is `.closest('td').find('.DivB')` and don't worry about micro-optimizations. It won't break when the DOM changes slightly and  will work in the scope of a single table cell which is probably what you need.

Edit: the question has been heavily edited, but `.closest()` still doesn't  do what you think it  does. Now you want `$('.LinkB').siblings(".LinkG");`